# I would like to make my new HP Envy 700-230qe Desktop a dual boot platform

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, bluetooth, hp

I am currently running Windows 8.1 -- 12GB memory -- 2TB Sata hard drive -- RJ-45 Ethernet connection -- and a Premium Wireless-N LAN card & Bluetooth

Does anyone have any information as to how I should partition my hard drive (I was thinking 50-50 for Windows & Ubuntu) plus anything on configuring my peripherals???

Regards,
Garth

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't need much disk space. You can partition your hard drive 50-50 but you don't have to. This [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) recommends 5 GB free disk space. I am not sure if it is still up to date, but 10 GB should be enough for a minimal installation.

How much disk space you really need, depends on the programs you are installing.

But, you have to consider where you want to store your private files (Music, Photos, Documents, etc.). Ubuntu is able to access your windows partion, so you can store this things primiliy there, but if you want to store them on the Ubuntu partion you need some more space for that.

Most of your peripherals should run out of the box, but that depends on your hardware. I suggest installing Ubuntu first. If something is not working, come back and ask again ;-)